# React hooks useMemo/useCallback skip

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I use `useMemo`'s or `useCallback`'s seconds argument to optimize based on a value inside the callback?

```
const [s, setS] = useState({ page: { title: 'a', index: 3 } });
const getPage = data => data.page;

const cb = useCallback(data => setS(data), [getPage(data)]);
//                                          ^ ain't no data here :(

useEffect(() => externalService.sub(cb));
```

Basically I want to pass the callback to an external service but I want the `setSomeState` only be called if the `data.page` has been changed.

I know I can wrap `setS` with another function and do a `shallowEqual` before calling it but was wondering if `useMemo` or `useCallback` provide something similar.

Comment: Don't see the problem with the code. Could you come up with a reproducible demo on codesandbox or something?

Comment: @YangshunTay, That's not a valid javascript code. `data` in `getPage(data)` call is not in the scope. It's not in the `lexical` scope, I should say.

Comment: I've asked similar question with real examples.
You can check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963248/whats-the-difference-between-usecallback-and-usememo-in-practice