# React hooks warn me for missing dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I am using useEffect to prefetch data on initial rendering:

```
function myComponent(props) {
    const { fetchSomething } = props;
    ...
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSomething();
    }, []);
    ...
    ...
}
```

My linter warn me for "React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies". It wants me to put `fetchSomething` inside the dependencies array.
The issue is that even it `fetchSomething` is going to be changed, I don't want the component to refetch the data. And as I see it, most of the situations where useEffect uses a function, it doesn't really care whether the function is changed.
I don't want to turn off that warning and doesn't like to spread `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` all over my code.
What is the rational behind such behavior?
It makes me feel insecure while using hooks, as if I am doing something incorrect.

Comment: Why does your consumer send a prop to load data on mount? Just have a function as a service and call that rather than a prop. If anything your fetchSomething would be a param or data to query off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useRef` or `useMemo` to store the value.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963730/9351632

Comment: So you suggest to add code (more complexity) in order to undergo lint issue? It doesn't make sense..

Comment: I did not mean more code. I meant instead of useEffect you use useMemo. It fetches only once and the returned value (which is a promise in this case) will be stored. UseMemo will only be executed when the value gets access and then it will use the cached value going forward.

Comment: Won't I get the same error for the dependencies in useMemo?

Comment: @Naor yes for useMemo you will but not useRef. useRef does not listen to dependencies and can be mutated directly without triggering a re-render. useMemo is kind of like combining useState and useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook to remember the value of `props.fetchSomething` on first rendering. This will resolve your issue with `eslint`

```
function myComponent(props) {
    const fetchSomethingRef = useRef(props.fetchSomething);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSomethingRef.current();
    }, []);
}
```

> The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class. [more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

Comment: So you suggest to add code (more complexity) in order to undergo lint issue? It doesn't make sense..

Comment: @Naor, look. You told that you don't want to turn off `exhaustive-deps` rule and you don't want to see this warning. But at the same time, you don't want to write some extra code to resolve this warning. If you know that `fetchSomething` never changes, just add it to the dependencies array. If it changes, you have to use extra code and add complexity if you want to resolve this warning. Or you could just ignore it. Or turn off the rule. There is no other way to resolve your issue. You just have to choose what to do.

Comment: Agree with you. I guess I am looking for the reason or best practices that are not cost in performance.

Comment: @Naor my solution is not bad for performance. React documentation says that `useRef` is just a container. You can perceive it as an instance property of a class. If you don't pass `useRef` to `ref` prop of React component or DOM element, it has no influence on performance or re-rendering or reconciliation. When you use `useRef`, it just stores the value that you have passed to it for the full lifetime of the component. Read more about `useRef` here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref and here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that useRef is hacky solution that adds unnecessary complexity. Honestly the best solution I found is to use a conditional inside of useEffect()

```
function myComponent(props) {
    const { fetchSomething } = props;
    const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false)
    ...
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
       if(!fetched) {
        fetchSomething();
        setFetched(true)
       }
    }, [fetched, fetchSomething]);
    ...
    ...
}
```

using the useEffect hook properly is a very complex topic. You can read this very long article about it

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

useEffect is still fairly new so there are still competing best practices. I wouldnt recommend useRef tho.

Comment: hmmm `useRef` adds unnecessary complexity, and `useState` no. Interesting..

Comment: useRef is an escape hatch that bypasses the virtual DOM, useState works with the virtual DOM like the rest of your React app.

Comment: could you get a link to the documentation for proofing your words? React FAQ says: "The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class."
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables