# What is the use case of useMemo in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need help to understand when to use `useMemo` hook in React vs `useState` + `useEffect`. From what I've understood after reading other questions on S.O. and websites :

- With `useState` you can create a value (changeable through the ***setter***) and you can use `useEffect` to do whatever you need if some of the dependencies listed in the **dependency array** changes. On first render for example your component will be rendered with the initial value passed to `useState`, then the effect will run and your component will re-render with the new value you set with the **setter** in your **effect**.
- With `useMemo` you can create a value that will be computed from a function you give to the hook and it will change if some of the dependencies in the **dependency array** changes. So far, to me, it looks like `useState` + `useEffect` except you don't have the **setter** to change the value. On render your useMemo will run if one of the dependencies has changed. Difference here : your component will wait for the value to be computed before rendering (not sure about this part).

From what I've read, `useMemo` should be used for heavy operations. But if it's blocks the rendering of the component what's the point ?
Some says that with the dependency array you can avoid unnecessary updates but I can also do it with useEffect without blocking the render ? If I don't have a heavy component to render, isn't it faster to use useEffect ?

Thank you :)

**Edit :**
I accepted Philip Feldmann's answer as it fits my needs. As suggested in the comments you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963248/whats-the-difference-between-usecallback-and-usememo-in-practice) for a global comparison :)

Comment: `useMemo` prevents unecessary reprocessing of expensive data by wrapping the returned value in a dependency check layer. Until one of the deps changes the value won't be reprocessed across renders (similar to `useCallback`). See [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: Yes but isn't there a dependency check on useEffect also ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between useCallback and useMemo in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963248/whats-the-difference-between-usecallback-and-usememo-in-practice)

Comment: I think it gives a great comparison of what's possible. I don't think it's a duplicate. I'll accept Philip Feldmann's answer. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `useEffect` runs after rendering as a side effect. That means that when you don't want to block the render loop, you can use your version.

That version will however trigger another rerender through calling the **setter**. 
The initial time to paint might be faster, but you'll instantly block the render loop again by setting the new value, which in most cases should be slower than just using `useMemo` directly.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Philip, It is correct that u can use both the `useEffect()` and `useMemo()` for achieving the same result at the end.

But the primary intention for creating `useMemo()` hook is to store computationally intensive functions and the primary intention for creation of `useEffect()` is to do some side effects like fetching data, or doing something in background which may or may not re render something like subscribing to event.

Now we can use both for other purposes, but `useMemo` is used when we want to render the value in the initial render itself, and `useEffect` is used to re render after a initial render, when background tasks to be done are time taking, as to provide good user experience.

So it's basically your choice to choose depending upon what type of task you are doing when you want to render that data.