# I'm confused about the consequences of using useEffect together with useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

Suppose I have a function whose behavior won't change over time, and I'm planning to use this function in a `useEffect` hook so I include it as a dependency to satisfy the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` ESLint rule:

```js
const doSomething = useCallback((args) => {...}, []);
useEffect(() => {
  doSomething();
}, [doSomething]);
```

This is the advised solution in [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#but-i-cant-put-this-function-inside-an-effect) by Dan Abramov, which works fine currently, but I'm confused about these descriptions of [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) in the React docs:

> `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`.

> You may rely on `useMemo` as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

Reading these, my impression is that the code above does NOT work without `useMemo`, as `useMemo` (and therefore `useCallback`) is a performance optimization method and isn't a semantic guarantee, so my `doSomething` function wrapped in `useCallback` is equivalent to:

```js
const doSomething = useMemo(() => (args) => {...}, []);
```

whose memoized value "React may choose to forget" in the future, and my `useEffect` callback would run again incorrectly.

Sometimes I use refs to store a function which feels safe but also unnecessary:

```js
const doSomething = useRef((args) => {...});
useEffect(() => {
  doSomething.current();
}, []);
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Here you can read about difference between `useCallback` and `useMemo`:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963730/1330105

Comment: I understand how the hooks work currently, (e.g.: how `useCallback` is similar to `useRef` right now), but I get the impression from the React docs, that `useCallback` will work similarly to `useMemo` in the future  (as in, it will be a performance optimization feature, rather than a semantic guarantee to skip rerender).