# useMemo is not working when sessionStorage is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an app which header contains icon which should be shown when the user is logged in. I keep my logged in info in `sessionStorage` but when it changes my component is not rendered again. I tried to use `useEffect` for that and `useMemo` but it doesn't worked.

The updating part:

```
const isLoggedIn = useMemo(() => sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged'), [sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged')]);
```

The usage:

```
      {isLoggedIn === 'true' ? ['left'].map((anchor) => (
        ...some jsx
      )) : null}
```

The `sessionStorage` value is a string: "false" or "true".

I have routes and constant header, the header is not a part of routes so when it changes my header is not rerenders so I tried to use useMemo for that.

Comment: Is there any issue with directly using it without `useMemo` like `const isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged');`? I doubt if hooks work on the dependencies other than `state`/`props`.

Comment: @PrathapReddy noo sorry, it's not working too :/

Comment: Gotcha. That's the real problem. Nothing to do with hooks.

Comment: Have you tried directly adding it in `return` jsx {`sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged') === 'true' ? ...}`

Comment: @PrathapReddy look I have routes and constant header, header is not a part of routes so when it changes my header is not rerenders so I tried to use useMemo for that, I hope it will help somehow

Comment: @PrathapReddy Yap I tried that way too

Comment: **but when it changes my component**, does it mean you are switching routes in the page!?

Comment: @PrathapReddy yes, I'm making redirect with useHistory's push method from my login page to push into the home page.

Comment: Updated my answer based on the clarification provided. Hope it helps 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer as per clarification gained through comments.

If you are using `Redux`:

I would recommend to **store** the user logged-in information in `redux store` and connect to the **isolated Header** component via **connect** HOC and `mapStateToProps`. Whenever you update (upon successful user login) the user login status the component will listen to `store` updates.

**Or**

You can use React `context` approach if there is no `redux` used

```
// Declare it outside of your App component/any other file and export it
const GlobalState = React.createContext();


// Declare state variable to store user logged in info inside of your App component
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

// Add them to context to access anywhere in your components via useContext
// In App render or where you have route mapping
<GlobalState.Provider value={{
  isLoggedIn,
  setIsLoggedIn
}}>
  ....
</GlobalState.Provider>

// Update the status using setIsLoggedIn upon successful login where you are making login call

// In your Header get it via useContext
const context = useContext(GlobalState);

`context.isLoggedIn` is what you need.

// You can use useEffect/useMemo approach to get the login status updates
```

Find more about [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) and [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: what about useContext? Can I implement it with it?

Comment: Yes absolutely possible. Let me update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please can you add the proper way how to add my state into the context, I don't want to do mistakes because of that :)

Comment: I have attached the docs like too to help on the usage of `context` properly. Are you already using **Context**? Or only using it for this purpose.

Comment: Cool, wait a minute while I'm trying it

Comment: Updated the answer with little more details on **context** and the approach.

Comment: Maan I don't know what is the problem, I'm using exactly as you wrote in the answer but it still not working, it doesn't see the context. Whatever I really appreciate your effort and I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Might be simple issue. We have been using it this way all the time if there is no redux. Are you able to **console log** the updated value of `isLoggedIn` in your **Header** component? Check out the exact code as per [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext). They have mentioned common mistakes people used to do as well. Give it a try since you are almost there. Just don't give up 

Comment: It worked, the problem was that I forgot to export/import my context. Thank you very much!!!

Comment:  If we learn something new then it's a good day. 

Answer (score 1):

sessionStorage is not an observer object and you have to store the current authentication state into a variable or React state and use that variable in your component. And when you authenticated the user, you should update the variable to `true` and change that to `false` when the user logged out.
To implement what I said, you can get help from these ways:

1. Redux
2. React context

You can implement the React context by your self from scratch or using the [React-hooks-global-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-global-state)

Comment: I also thought in that way and tried to store the result of sessionStorage into my components state and update my state every time sessionStorage changes the isLogged value with `useEffect` but it doesn't work too :/

Answer (score 0):

UseMemo is used for memoizing calculated values. You should be using useCallback.useCallback is used for memoizing function references.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963248/whats-the-difference-between-usecallback-and-usememo-in-practice/54963730)

```
const isLoggedIn = useCallback(() => sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged'), [sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put your `sessionStorage` data into `State` and update that state? As far as I know, react will not know about the session storage. So even if you change the manipulate the data in the sessionStorage directly it won't gonna update your UI.

```
let [storeData, setStoreData] = useState(true);

let isLoggedIn = useMemo(() => ({ sessionData: storeData }), [storeData]);

 {isLoggedIn === 'true' ? ['left'].map((anchor) => (
    ...some jsx
  )) : null}


 <button
   onClick={() => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("isLogged", !storeData);
      setStoreData(sessionStorage.getItem("isLogged"));
   }} > Update Store </button>
```