# Question regarding benefit of React useCallback hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am studying React, and I am stuck on understanding the benefits of `useCallback` hook. According to this [website](https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/),

> In function components, the execution of the whole function is the equivalent of the render function in class components.

If in the functional components, the whole function is executed on every render, doesn't that mean that the whole code would be re-executed afresh. As a result the `useCallback` hook would start from a clean state on each render, meaning that `useCallback` cache would be reinitialized and all previous cache entries would be lost?

Comment: Show how you are trying to use `useCallback`.  The whole goal of it is memoization so that you don't have to reconstruct the same thing over and over.  You may or may not be doing so based on your implementation.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54963248/691711

Comment: Check this [link](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback).

Comment: All *your* code is run fresh, but react saves values between renders, if you ask it to. useCallback is one way to ask it to.