# Should I use memoization or callback when passing a function as parameter of a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I wrote a custom hook that accepts an async function as parameter.

The custom hook will call the function and return the result when done.

Should I memoize or useCallback when passing the function ?

Here's a sample usage of my hook

```js
    const {
        status,
        error,
        fire,
        data
    } = useAsyncOperation(
        () => {
            return Promise.resolve("Async result");
        },
        { autofire: true }
    );
```

What I fear is that inline anonymous function will change across renders and that the hook consider it as a new value (even if the function is the same).

How should I handle this ?

FYI: I've set up a [code sandbox to illustrate the use of my custom hook](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-moon-dtw28q)

And the code of my hook is:

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult> = {
    status: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'success' | 'error';
    fire: () => Promise<TResult>;
    error?: Error;
    data?: TResult;
};

type UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult> = {
    onSuccess?: (result: TResult) => void;
    onError?: (error: Error) => void;
    autofire?: boolean;
};

export const useAsyncOperation = <TResult>(
    operation: () => Promise<TResult>,
    options: UseAsyncOperationOptions<TResult> = {}
): UseAsyncOperationResult<TResult> => {
    // TODO: use reducer to manage state in a cleaner way
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<'idle' | 'pending' | 'success' | 'error'>('idle');
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | undefined>();
    const [data, setData] = useState<TResult | undefined>();
    const [autofired, setAutofired] = useState(false);

    const { onSuccess, onError, autofire } = options;

    const fire = useCallback(async () => {
        setStatus('pending');
        try {
            const result = await operation();
            setStatus('success');
            setData(result);
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(result);
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            setStatus('error');
            setError(error as Error);
            if (onError) onError(error as Error);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }, [onError, onSuccess, operation]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (autofire && !autofired) {
            console.log('autofire');
            setAutofired(true);
            void fire();
        }
    }, [autofire, fire, autofired]);

    return {
        status,
        fire,
        error,
        data,
    };
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between useCallback and useMemo in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963248/whats-the-difference-between-usecallback-and-usememo-in-practice)

Comment: I don't ask what are useCallback and useMemo. I ask if my use case require the use of either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to keep the reference of the callback that you are passing to the `useAsyncOperation`.

The way how to determine when you have to use `useCallback` or not for functions is to check if that function is tracked as dependency. And your custom hook tracks `operation` in `useCallback`, and the result is also tracked in `useEffect`.

If you do not keep the reference of your `operation` callback, `fire` will get a new reference on each render, since it tracks `operation`. And this will lead to trigger `useEffect` as well, since it tracks `fire`

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I wonder if there is a way to behaves like useCallback, in a way the caller does not have to worry about deps.

Comment: Yes you can. There are some tricks with useRef you can do. Assign the function to the ref.current on each render and inside the effect use ref.current instead of the function itself

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the `operation` changes (ie - arrow function would change on each render), the `useCallback` would change and trigger the `useEffect`. However, calling the `useEffect` is fine, because after the 1st call the `autofired` flag would prevent other calls.

However, if still want to avoid re-creating the memoized `fire` function, and you don't want (and can't) force the users to always memoize the `operation` (via `useCallback`), use a ref to hold the `operation`:

```
const opRef = useRef(operation);

// update opRef on each render
useEffect(() => {
  opRef.current = operation;
})

const fire = useCallback(async() => {
  setStatus('pending');
  try {
    const result = await opRef.current(); // call the function that is stored in the ref
    setStatus('success');
    setData(result);
    if (onSuccess) onSuccess(result);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    setStatus('error');
    setError(error as Error);
    if (onError) onError(error as Error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}, [onError, onSuccess]); // remove operation
```