# React Native with Lodash Debounce: useCallback or useMemo

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, lodash, debouncing

I made a composant that run a search to an API once the text changes with lodash's `debounce`.

I made it works either by using `useCallback` and `useMemo` but I can't understand the differences (advantages/inconvenients) **if** there is any between those two version outside of syntax.

I quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64987636/2254425 so I assume there is **no functional differences** between my functions `debounceWithDataMemo` and `debounceWithDataCallback` but I would appreciate a confirmation with this concrete example and be sure I'm doing things correctly.

> useMemo will remember the returned value from your function.
>
> useCallback will remember your actual function.

```js
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";
//[...]
const SearchThroughAPI = ({location}) => {
    const DEBOUNCE_TIMER = 300;
    const [ stateText, setStateText ] = useState(null);
    const [ results, setResults ] = useState([]);

    const handleChangeText = (text) => {
        setStateText(text);
        debounceWithDataMemo(text); // or debounceDataWithDataCallback(text)
    };

    //run queries only after a debounce: with useMemo
    const debounceWithDataMemo = useMemo(() => debounce((text) => requestFirebase(text), DEBOUNCE_TIMER),[location]);
    const requestFirebase = (query) => {
        //code to run the api call and update results Hook State
    };

    //run queries only after a debounce: with useCallback
    const debounceDataWithDataCallback = useCallback(debounce(query => {
        //code to run the api call and update results Hook State
    }, DEBOUNCE_TIMER), [location]);

    const Item = ({title,source,id}) => (<Text style={[styles.title, source == "firebase" ? {color: "#FFF"} : null]}>{id}: {title}</Text>);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <TextInput onChangeText={handleChangeText}/>
            </View>
            {results?.length ? 
            <FlatList 
                data={results} 
                renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.description} source={item.source} id={item.id} />}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id} 
            /> 
            : null}
        </View>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

useMemo is designed to cache value. According to the docs, the function inside useMemo should be pure, have no arguments, and will be called during the initial render.

In your code, the useMemo will return

```
debounce((text) => requestFirebase(text), DEBOUNCE_TIMER)
```

which is the same as the function inside your useCallback.

From my perspective, if you want to have some value calculated immediately after the initial render, useMemo is the choice. If you want to have some value to be calculated later, after an event (e.g. mouse click), use useCallback.